# How to declare reserved words as variables in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the best way to bypass the [Oracle SQL reserved-word constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm) for PL/SQL value declaration?  I realize [bind and substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer) may be acceptable alternatives for an actual query, but what about Oracle PL/SQL?  For example I would like to declare a numeric variable as "num", structured below within the Oracle PL query:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
  num number;
begin
   num := 10;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('The value of num ' || num); 
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NUM` is not a reserved word.

**The best way is not to use reserved words.**

If you insist on using them, you can put them between quotation marks. This does not work:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
  begin number;
begin
   begin := 10;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('The value of begin ' || begin); 
end;
/
```

This does:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
  "begin" number;
begin
   "begin" := 10;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('The value of begin ' || "begin"); 
end;
/
```

Quotation marks also make the variable name case-sensitive. `"begin"`, `"Begin"` and `"BEGIN"` are different variables.

Comment: that's strange because my Oracle SQL Developer output window was treating it as an error; I re-ran my script in my question and now it passes.  In any case, I was looking for the appropriate bypass with quotes as you suggested-thank you!

Comment: Would upvote 20 times if I could - there should really be no reason to ever use a reserved word as a variable/column name. If you are using a reserved word, chances are your variable/column name isn't descriptive enough. With a variable it's easy to have a prepend on it (`my_timestamp` as an example).

Comment: `begin number;` will make your app non-portable and your debugging difficult. Anyone who uses reserved words in PL/SQL (or anywhere) should be **committed** :-) You have IIRC 30 whole characters per identifier - the manual says you can quote reserved words, but this is `not recommended`.

Comment: To add to that - DON'T DO IT. Its just not worth it. I've turned up at client sites to find that users insisted on certain names for table columns that included reserved words as well as 'non-standard' characters, e.g. '-'. I see it as a lack of consideration for anyone running or debugging code later.